# How to get label using FedEx Web Services?

Tags: php, fedex

I am using my developer credentials for FedEx web services, with RocketShipIt API, which is only a XML wrapper.

Problem is that label_img variable is constantly empty:

Here is sample code I use:

```
$shipment = new \RocketShipIt\Shipment('fedex');
$shipment->setParameter('service', 'FEDEX_2_DAY');
$shipment->setParameter('toCompany', 'John Doe');
$shipment->setParameter('toName', 'John Doe');
$shipment->setParameter('toPhone', '1234567891');
$shipment->setParameter('toAddr1', '111 W Legion');
$shipment->setParameter('toCity', 'Whitehall');
$shipment->setParameter('toState', 'MT');
$shipment->setParameter('toCode', '59759');
$shipment->setParameter('toCountry', 'US');
$shipment->setParameter('packagingType', 'FEDEX_ENVELOPE');

$shipment->setParameter('length', '5');
$shipment->setParameter('width', '5');
$shipment->setParameter('height', '5');
$shipment->setParameter('weight','0.1');


$response = $shipment->submitShipment();

echo "<pre>";
print_r($response);
echo "<pre>";
```

And response I get:

```
Array
(
    [status] => SUCCESS
    [charges] => 17.61
    [trk_main] => 794663231443
    [tracking_detail] => Array
        (
            [id] => 794663231443
            [type] => FEDEX
        )

    [pkgs] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [pkg_trk_num] => 794663231443
                    [label_fmt] => PNG
                    [label_img] => 
                    [cod_return_label_img] => 
                )

        )

)
```

I have searched all over FedEx and RocketShipIt documentation, without any luck. I have no further idea why is my label_img empty. Maybe because I am using developer credentials? But then idea of developer test credentials is misused.